# AddIdentity .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to install the Nuget Package to use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1 but I get the following error message.

```
Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'xxxx'.
```

I created a brand new project in Visual Stuido 2017 so is nothing to do with anything else I have installed.

Comment: It says it right there in the error message: it only supports .NET 4.5, and not .NET Core

Comment: Well I don't understand then? I started a .Net Core app and now I can't add a .net core package?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to install this package instead? `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`

Comment: Thank you! Yes installed the wrong project type :)

Answer (score 1):

The string (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) is the clue.  It means the package cannot be used with ASP.NET Core.  It is a sure sign you have the wrong package.

Just because the package name contains the word 'core' doesn't mean it works with ASP.NET core.  This explained by Pierre-Loup Pagniez in his answer [What is the difference between Microsoft.Aspnet.identity.Core vs Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140952/what-is-the-difference-between-microsoft-aspnet-identity-core-vs-microsoft-aspne)