# .Net Core API Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core

**My question.**

So my question is how do I connect a .Net Core API using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity  to an identity (AspNetUser) table created using .Net 4.5 and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

**The Details.**

I have a MVC web application that allows user to register an login, and view certain information based on there credentials. This was written in .Net4.5. and I'm assuming using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core. (Which I think is the non .NET core version. ITs not the best naming convention) This project cant be changed.

I'm trying to extend some of the features such as login and register to use an API. I'm trying to build the API in .Net Core and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

I have created a simple test login controller.

```
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public AuthController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
                              SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
                                 IConfiguration config)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _config = config; ;
        }

 

      
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDto user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var testResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Username, user.Password, false, false);
                return Ok(testResult);
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Originally I was getting invalid column errors, as it seems that the AspNetUsers table is now created with additional fields compared with the AspNetUsers table created by the .NET4.5 system.

I got round this issue by ignoring them in the ModelBuilderof the dbcontext class

```
    {

        public AuthConext(DbContextOptions<AuthConext> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                                             .Ignore(c => c.TwoFactorEnabled)
                                             .Ignore(c => c.SecurityStamp)
                                             .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnabled)
                                             .Ignore(c => c.NormalizedEmail)
                                             .Ignore(c => c.NormalizedUserName)
                                             .Ignore(c => c.ConcurrencyStamp)
                                             .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnd);
        }
    }
```

However I'm not getting errors regarding the LINQ query.

```
    .Where(i => i.NormalizedUserName == __normalizedUserName_0)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of member 'NormalizedUserName' on entity type 'IdentityUser' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, LambdaExpression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.FindByNameAsync(String normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
   at MyFirstChoice_Api_CORE.Controllers.AuthController.Login(LoginDto user) in C:\Repos\MyFirstChoice_Api_CORE\MyFirstChoice_Api_CORE\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

While it does suggest a solution. I'm not sure where to make that change as I'm not creating a query myself just simply calling _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync.

So my question is how to I connect and .Net Core API using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity  to and identity table created using .net 4.5 and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core seem to not have a lot in common

[What is the difference between Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140952/what-is-the-difference-between-microsoft-aspnet-identity-core-and-microsoft-aspn/41141049)

However Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity is a .net standard library so it should be compatible with .net core / 5 apps

So you should just try to use it in your web api

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-json-web-tokens/